# Isoperimetric inequality in the Poincare disc

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

In the Poincare disc model, a version of the isoperimetric inequality states that $L(\partial(A))>c\mu(A),$ where $\mu$ is the hyperbolic area and $L(\gamma)=\int_0^1 \frac{|\gamma'(t)|}{1-|\gamma(t)|^2},$ for a curve $\{\gamma(t)\}_{t=0}^1$ and for some positive constant $c$.

Is there an elementary proof of this result, and what is the best constant possible here? I guess for a fixed area the set which minimizes the size of the boundary is the disc of that given area, we can check that the constant here would be $1$.

Furthermore, if we restrict our class of sets $A$ to large sets (say, those sets $A$ which contain a ball $B(z, r)$ for some $z\in A$ and large $r$), can we make the constant c in the inequality as large as we want by taking $r$ large?

Any help or references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering what the Poincare disk model has to do with it, I guess you just mean the curvature = -1. (because the curvature is -1 in the Poincare disk model)

Then the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ is 
$ 2\pi \sinh (r)$

And the area is:
$ 2\pi ( \cosh (r) - 1) $

So your formula becomes:
$ \frac{\cosh (r) - 1}{r \sinh (r)} $

Plotting this function it looks to have a limit at r=0 of .5 and it is decreasing away from it all the way to 0

Hopes this helps

Comment: Where does the $r$ in the denominator come from?